# Why are we double tagging MCU and Marvel Comics questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I edited a question in the re-open queue earlier, and removed the Marvel tag (it was tagged `marvel` `marvel-cinematic-universe` `spider-man` `avengers-infinity-war`) because it seemed redundant.  However, I was directed in a comment ([Is Maw Peter's First Kill?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188732/is-maw-peters-first-kill?noredirect=1#comment513797_188732)) that I should have read the tag wiki first, and seen that it is a required tag for any MCU or Marvel Comics question.

To me, Marvel is implied in their own cinematic universe, and their comics.  Why are we tagging things this way?

Comment: Seems dupey to me...

Comment: Perhaps, but it would mean we shouldn't have tagged the question in my question with `marvel`.  The upper limit of that hierarchy would *be* the MCU, which is separate from the comics, and the X-Men, and Fantastic Four, and....

Comment: Or, perhaps we tag all the comics and MCU's with `marvel`, I am starting to see how that might make sense, but then based on the wiki we'd have to pull the `marvel` tag from all non-comics and non-MCU questions.

Answer (score 5):

It is redundant, but Stack Exchanges tagging system requires us to make some compromises, and this stack chose redundant tags.

The issue is that our content naturally falls into a hierarchical tagging model. A large portion of our works can be tagged as individual works, which are part of a series, which may be part of a larger universe, and in extreme cases like Marvel, part of a massive body of interrelated works, e.g.:

*Iron Man 3* >> the *Iron Man* series >> The MCU >> Marvel

Stack Exchange tags can't naturally represent this hierarchy. Thus, in order to allow our users flexibility in using tags to search, filter, build custom RSS feeds, ignore, highlight, etc. at any level of this hierarchy, we've settled on just using redundant tags. That is, tag things with all levels of the tag chain that are relevant.

Comment: You seem to be against this use of redundant tags, yet iirc it was you who originally suggested it

Comment: because the alternatives are all worse.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very helpful :)